# Tensorflow object detection api mis classifying objects

Tags: tensorflow

I followed a simple [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku) to train a custom object detector.
I got my loss up to 0.6, however my issue is that the detected will classify other objects as what I've trained it with. For example in my case it classifies a dog as macarooni and cheese. 
What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly the same issue, where the model "remembered" the previous objects. There is a new configuration in the config file that is was not implemented when the video was made.

Inside the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_pet.config` file you have to specify the path to the checkpoint where the training will start, so it will have all the weights from the previous training, this config is `fine_tune_checkpoint`, below that there is `from_detection_checkpoint` so it will use the specified checkpoint, after that there is `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars` which is set to `true` by default, but must be `false` if you want the model to "forget" the objects that it was trained on.

The problem is that `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars` will load and fix all the weights, including the ones in the final layers not just the lower layer ones, so it will remember the classification and detection from past objects and misclassify with the new ones, since your `*.pbtxt` has different classifications. If you set it to `false` it will load the data and learn new weights for the final layers based only on your training set.